# Gunn oscillator question

Tags: rf

I was asked to first design a Gunn oscillator for a frequency of \$10GHz\$, feeding an  output line of impedance \$50ohm\$. I was told that the Gunn could be represented as a diode of impedance \$Z_D=-20+j60\$ ohm and was asked to connect it to a transmission line of impedance \$Z_c=100ohm\$. I managed to solve that and determine the necessary stub lengths etc. rendering oscillations possible using a Smith Chart.

I am now asked to implement this design for a Gunn oscillator on a dielectric bed using microstrips; moreover, to show the feeding DC network and the RF output so that optimal isolation between the DC and RF ports is attained. Is the third drawing in the attachment the one meeting the requirements? I'm not sure and would be thankful for some guidance.

[image]

Comment: Is anyone here familiar with this topic?

Comment: this looks like homework.  If so, you should say so.  I don't believe you could draw these asking the question as you have.

Comment: It's a small project I am working on. An academic assignment.

Comment: ok, to start, a test. l would imagine you want AC coupled output.  Does this apply to any of them? NOTE: not necessarily required or important

Comment: @johnnymopo I think it applies to the last diagram. All these diagrams were provided by the professor.

Comment: What VSWR specs?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf it wasn't specified. In fact, I have no further information than what I provided above. I can however add the lengths of the stub and the transmission line I found using the SC, prerequisites for oscillations. How can I help you help me? :-)

Comment: Anyone willing to try and help with this? I'd appreciate any feedback.